# Как писать прилагательное, образованное от имени собственного?

Tags: орфография

Рельсы — имя собственное, образованное от название технологии Ruby on Rails.
Я учу Рельсы. *Рельсы* пишем с прописной (большой) буквы.
А как писать: «Я люблю *рельсовую* реализацию моделей»?
С одной стороны, я думаю, что стоит применять правило «[Правописание прилагательных, образованных от географических названий](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9/)», т. е. писать со строчной (маленькой) буквы. Я прав?

Answer (score 7):

Ну, тут на мой взгляд, не может быть правоты или неправоты никакой, кроме статистической. По факту в любых прилагательных, образованных от начинающихся с заглавной буквы в английском технологий, мы всё пишем в нижнем регистре.

Примеры:

- Я не хочу возиться с этими спринговыми конфигами.
- Там котлиновый стек.

То есть, вы правы и пишется "рельсовый".

Comment: Большое спасибо, что подтвердили мои мысли.